# Trying to hard-code an image into an object array in my controller

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, image, ionic-framework

How would I add an image to this array using Javascript:

```
$scope.painScoreLabel = "Select Pain Score";
$scope.painScore = [
    {
        'value': 0,
        'label': "No pain"
    }, {
        'value': 1,
        'label': "Slight pain"
    }, {
        'value': 2,
        'label': "Intermittent pain at rest / moderate pain on movement"
    }, {
        'value': 3,
        'label': "Moderate pain at rest / severe pain on movement"
    }, {
        'value': 4,
        'label': "Severe pain at rest"
    }
];
```

but its not working!

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.painScore = [
{
    'value': 0,
    'label': "No pain"
}, {
    'value': 1,
    'label': "Slight pain"
}, {
    'value': 2,
    'label': "Intermittent pain at rest / moderate pain on movement"
}, {
    'value': 3,
    'label': "Moderate pain at rest / severe pain on movement"
}, {
    'value': 4,
    'label': "Severe pain at rest"
}];

for(var i in painScore){
    painScore[i]["image"] = i+"img.png";
}
alert(JSON.stringify(painScore));
```

In this way you can add image to your JSON object. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13adde1h/)

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through on all the elements of the array and for each object create a new key and set the value to anything you want.
The value can be a source to an image . also the value can be base64 string of an image.

Comment: Could you show me an example of how you would create a new key?